# Find maximum of a function

Tags: optimization, math, max

I need to find a maximum of the function:

a1^x1 * const1 + a2^x2 * const2 +....+ ak^xk * constk = qaulity

where xk>0 and xk is integer. ak is constant.

constraint: 
a1^x1 * const1*func(x1) + a2^x2 * const2*func(x2) +....+ ak^xk * constk*func(xk) < Budget

Where func is a discrete function:

```
func(x)
{
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1: return 423;
        case 2: return 544;
        ...
        etc
    }
}
```

k may be big(over 1000). x less then 100.
What is the best method?

Comment: You have a function of over 1000 variables...?

Comment: Yeah, a few thousands variables...

Comment: Isn't this the knapsack problem in disguise?

Comment: This is known as integer programming, one of the methods to solve integer programmes is branch-and-bound search

Answer (score 2):

There are techniques like nelder-mead optimization (which I believe GSL implements), but most techniques assume some sort of special structure (i.e. convexity or continuity).  Depending on the values of the function, there may not exist a unique optimum or even an optimum that a normal downhill method can find.

Comment: Do you mean "an optimum that a normal downhill method **cannot** find"